# Why do I keep getting application-defined or object-defined error with simple VBA macro?

Tags: excel, vba, debugging, runtime-error

I am working on creating a macro to simplify things that I do on a daily basis. The idea behind this macro is to copy 7 worksheets from the parent report, open a new workbook, paste and hardcode the data, save it to my desktop and close the new workbook.

As I am working through debugging and testing my code I am running into a problem which I do not understand why it is happening. If I boot up windows and run the macro the first time in my excel workbook, I get no issues the first time I run it for the 7 reports. The problem comes up when I try to add code or fix issues and run the code again. I keep getting " Run-time error '1004' Application-defined or object defined error".

I am trying to debug and when I hit F8 for debugging and stepping into the code, it seems it gets hung up around step #4 when it is trying to close when I run it more than once. I am learning and using Leila Gharani's course, but I don't think I got this far in the course yet to understand. If someone can please help me so I can understand this concept, I would greatly appreciate it.

Thank you

```
'1. Select Parent Report and select BD Tab
Workbooks("Parent Report").Activate
Worksheets("BD").Select

'2. Select all cells from BD tab, open new workbook , paste data, and hardcode it.
Cells.Select
Cells.Copy
Workbooks.Add
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
Cells.Select
Cells.Copy
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
Cells.EntireRow.AutoFit

'3. Rename worksheet to BD and cell "A2" to BD.
ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Name = "BD"
Range("A2").Value = "BD"
Range("A1").Select

'4. Save current flash report to local drive, with monthly naming format and close it.
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "C:\Users\mylocaldriveinfo\Desktop\Flash Reports" & "\BD Monthly Reporting - Preliminary " & Format(Date, "mmm") & " " & Format(Date, "yyyy")
ActiveWorkbook.Close
```

Comment: _The idea behind this macro is to copy 7 worksheets_ - The code shown only copied 1 sheet.

Comment: I only used this block because this is the beginning of the code and it doesn't move passed step 4 above. the rest of the code is identical, with the exception of the name of worksheets.

Comment: First, as a general rule, try to never call `Workbook.Activate`, `Worksheet.select`, nor `Range.Select` and the likes. For your issue, is `ActiveWorkbook` the workbook you saved you macro into? Because if it is, I do not know what happens to the VBA code when it tries to close itself... could work sometimes and fail others (I have just read your code super quickly to rule that out before having a more detailed look).

Comment: Is the idea to copy just the values i.e. no formatting, no formulas. What are the other 6 
 sheet names ?

Comment: i have it and need it to copy the formatting and values. it will also copy the formulas, but then one of the next steps is to copy all the data in the new workbook and hardcode it.

Comment: @Atmo, I don't have it saved in a workbook. I have it saved in a text document and then in the parent report im using, i go to the ThisWorkbook object, paste my code, and run it that way. this is probably really bad and a much better approach that I am unaware of

Comment: You're saving the spreadsheet with identical names only differing in month and year. If you do not delete these files before trying to run this code again, it will throw an error because this file name already exists.

Comment: @Plutian could it be possible that there is a lag with one drive? I have been deleting the files each time so it doesn't get caught up on itself, and when I restart my PC, it works again no problem. not sure if there is a lag

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out. It was my one drive at work giving me an issue. I disabled it, as I never use it and doing so I have not been able to replicate the error.

I am sure this code isn't best practice, but it works for now.

Answer (score 0):

```vb
Option Explicit
Sub CopySheets()

    Const FOLDER = "C:\Users\mylocaldriveinfo\Desktop\Flash Reports\BD Monthly Reporting -"

    Dim wbNew As Workbook, wbMaster As Workbook, sht, n As Long

    Set wbMaster = ThisWorkbook

    ' create new workbook
    Set wbNew = Workbooks.Add(1) ' 1 sheet
    n = 1

    For Each sht In Array("BD", "Sheet2", "Sheet3", "Sheet4", _
                      "Sheet5", "Sheet6", "SHeet7") ' 7 sheet names
        
        wbMaster.Sheets(sht).Copy After:=wbNew.Sheets(n)
        n = n + 1
        With wbNew.Sheets(n)
            .UsedRange.Value = .UsedRange.Value
            .Range("A2") = sht
        End With
    Next
    
    With wbNew
        ' delete blank sheet
        Application.DisplayAlerts = False
        .Sheets(1).Delete
        Application.DisplayAlerts = True
    
        ' save
        .SaveAs Filename:=FOLDER & Format(Date, "mmm yyyy")
        .Close
    End With
    MsgBox "Done", vbInformation
      
End Sub
```